# Por que mi RecyclerView no se muestra?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un fallo en mi programa, he estado revisando con el debugger, he encontrado el fallo, pero no se como solucionarlo, mi problema es que el ViewHolder se llena correctamente, pero a la hora de mostrarlo, no se por qué, pero no sale

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lV;
private List<Object> empresas = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lV = findViewById(R.id.lista);

    empresas.add(new EmpresaTecnologica("Company S.A.", R.drawable.emptec1, "https://company.com", "Aquí", "mail123"));
    empresas.add(new EmpresaTecnologica("Adidas", R.drawable.empnotec1, "https://company.com", "Aquí", "mail123"));
    empresas.add(new EmpresaTecnologica("Amazon", R.drawable.emptec2, "https://company.com", "Aquí", "mail123"));
    empresas.add(new EmpresaTecnologica("CocaCola", R.drawable.empnotec2, "https://company.com", "Aquí", "mail123"));

    ListaDinamica a = new ListaDinamica(this);
    lV.setAdapter(a);
    //TODO listener del click
}

class ListaDinamica extends BaseAdapter {
    Context c;

    public ListaDinamica(Context c) {
        super();
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (getItem(position) instanceof EmpresaTecnologica) {
            return 0; //es empresa tecnologica
        } else {
            return 1; //es empresa no tecnologica
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return empresas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return empresas.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        ImageView img = null;
        TextView txtNombreEmpresa = null;
        TextView txtLocalizacion = null;
        TextView txtMail = null;
        TextView txtCodigoCnae;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) { // es empresa tecnologica
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.emp_tecnologicas, parent, false);
                img = row.findViewById(R.id.logo);
                txtLocalizacion = row.findViewById(R.id.localizacion);
                txtMail = row.findViewById(R.id.mail);
                txtNombreEmpresa = row.findViewById(R.id.nombreEmpresa); //TODO mejorar esto para no repetir codigo

            }/*else{ // es empresa no tecnologica
                row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.emp_no_tecnologicas, parent, false);
                txtCodigoCnae = row.findViewById(R.id.codigoCnae);
                txtNombreEmpresa = row.findViewById(R.id.nombreEmpresa); //TODO mejorar esto para no repetir codigo
                holder = new ViewHolder(txtNombreEmpresa, txtCodigoCnae);
            }*/
                holder = new ViewHolder(img, txtNombreEmpresa, txtLocalizacion, txtMail);
                row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            }

            if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
                holder.getTxtNombreEmpresa().setText(((EmpresaTecnologica) empresas.get(position)).getNombreEmpresa());
                holder.getImg().setImageResource(((EmpresaTecnologica) empresas.get(position)).getIdLogo());
                holder.getTxtLocalizacion().setText(((EmpresaTecnologica) empresas.get(position)).getLocalizacion());
                holder.getTxtMail().setText(((EmpresaTecnologica) empresas.get(position)).getMail());
            } /*else {
                holder.getTxtNombreEmpresa().setText(((EmpresaNoTecnologica) empresas.get(position)).getNombreEmpresa());
                holder.getTxtCodigoCnae().setText(((EmpresaNoTecnologica) empresas.get(position)).getCodigoCnae());
            }*/

            return row;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView img;
        TextView txtNombreEmpresa;
        TextView txtLocalizacion;
        TextView txtMail;
        TextView txtCodigoCnae;

        public ViewHolder(ImageView img, TextView txtNombreEmpresa, TextView txtLocalizacion, TextView txtMail) {
            this.img = img;
            this.txtNombreEmpresa = txtNombreEmpresa;
            this.txtLocalizacion = txtLocalizacion;
            this.txtMail = txtMail;
        }

        public ViewHolder(TextView txtNombreEmpresa, TextView txtCodigoCnae) {
            this.txtNombreEmpresa = txtNombreEmpresa;
            this.txtCodigoCnae = txtCodigoCnae;
        }

        public ImageView getImg() {
            return img;
        }

        public TextView getTxtNombreEmpresa() {
            return txtNombreEmpresa;
        }

        public TextView getTxtLocalizacion() {
            return txtLocalizacion;
        }

        public TextView getTxtMail() {
            return txtMail;
        }

        public TextView getTxtCodigoCnae() {
            return txtCodigoCnae;
        }
    }
}
```

Estos son los layouts:
(activity_main.xml)

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

(emp_no_tecnologicas.xml)

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nombreEmpresa"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/codigoCnae"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/nombreEmpresa" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

(emp_tecnologicas.xml)

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nombreEmpresa"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/logo" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/localizacion"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/nombreEmpresa" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mail"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/localizacion" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Me gustaría saber como solucionar el error, he intentado arreglarlo durante horas, pero no he dado con la solución

Comment: this is "StackOverflow in Spanish". Report in "stackoverflow.com" pleas

Comment: **cuz I did it in spanish since im spanish** and we are at [es.so], please translate your question, otherwise it will be closed. Bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Por favor, traduce tu pregunta al castellano o de lo contrario terminará cerrada. Si deseas hacer la pregunta en inglés, debes hacerla en el sitio en inglés: [so]. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Culpa mía, no lo sabía

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error que figura en el `LogCat` @Ozgewn ? En tu pregunta mencionas un `RecyclerView` pero en tu código usas un `ListView`, ¿Por qué?

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo El problema es que en el `LogCat` si filtro por `Error` no me aparece ningún error.
Uso `ListView` porque hasta el momento, me había funcionado perfectamente, siguiendo este mismo modelo que he publicado

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no estas usando un `RecyclerView`, estas usando un `ListView`.
Estas usando un Adapter que corresponde a un RecyclerView, primeramente cambia la vista que usas en tu layout `activity_main.xml` de `ListView`:

```
<ListView
```

a usar un `RecyclerView`:

```
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

Revisa la documentación:

[**Cómo crear listas dinámicas con RecyclerView**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview?hl=es-419)

Comment: Pero, en anteriores aplicaciones siempre he usado `ListView` siguiendo este modelo, y siempre me ha funcionado (o, por lo menos, siempre ha aparentado funcionar), entonces, el único error que has podido ver es este de cambiar el `ListView` por el `RecyclerView` ?